# Tangent of a circle lesson

Tags: analytic-geometry

I'm confuse on solving this problem:

Find the equation of the circle which is tangent to the line $3x-2y=5$ at $(3,2)$ and it is passing through $(-2,1)$.

Can you pretty answer and explain how did you do the solution?

Please. I barely need to understand this lesson a lot better. Thank you.

Comment: When you write "Touching", do you mean "tangentially" ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be the centre of such circle. Then

i) $(x_0,y_0)$ stays on the line orthogonal to $3x-2y=5$ at $(3,2)$:
$$2(x-3)+3(y-2)=0$$
that is
$$2x+3y=12.$$
ii) $(x_0,y_0)$ stays on the perpendicular bisector of the segment of extreme points $(3,2)$ and $(-2,1)$:
$$(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2=(x+2)^2+(y-1)^2$$
that is
$$5x+y=4$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Can you help me? How to solve it?

Comment: @Trixie Are you able to find the equation of the line in i)?

Comment: What common property do all points have that lie on a bisector of a line segment?